# How to write function to return plot but also an object (data.frame)?

Tags: r, dataframe, function

**Description and goal:** In R Studio, I would like to define a function that drops columns of a given data.frame if it contains a too high share of missing values, defined by a cutoff value in percent. This function should return information about the subsetted data.frame (number of remaining columns and remaining share of missing cases) together with the subsetted data.frame itself for further analyses. Additionally, there should be an option to visualize remaining missing cases using the function `vis_miss()` of the identically named package.

**Packages used:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vismiss)
```

**Data:**

```
my.data <- tibble(col_1 = c(1:5),
                  col_2 = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA))
```

**My function:**

```
cut_cols <- function(df, na.perc.cutoff, vis_miss=FALSE) {
  df <- df[lapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) / length(x)) < na.perc.cutoff]
  cat(paste0("Remaining cols: ", ncol(df)),
      paste0("\nRemaining miss: ", paste0(round(sum(is.na(df)) / prod(dim(df)) * 100, 2), "%\n")))
  if (vis_miss==TRUE) {return(vis_miss(df[1:nrow(df),c(1:ncol(df))], warn_large_data=F))}
  df
}
```

**Test:**

```
cut_cols(my.data, 0.5, vis_miss = F) # without visualization
cut_cols(my.data, 0.5, vis_miss = T) # with visualization
```

**Problem:**
As you might have already seen in the example above, only the first line, where `vis_miss = F` actually returns the data.frame but not the second line, where `vis_miss = T`. I assume that this is because of the extra `if () {}` clause, which returns a plot and then ends the process without printing `df`. Is there a way to prevent this from happening so that the first line also returns the new data.frame?

Comment: You could wrap the result in a list: `list(df, plot)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct in your suspicion that the `if(){}` clause was stopping the df from printing. I think `return()` stops any function from running further. If that's the case then it's best practice to put it at the end of any function.

Further, use `print(df)` to make sure your function outputs your data frame. Here are a few changes to your code

```
cut_cols <- function(df, na.perc.cutoff, vis_miss=FALSE) {
  df <- df[lapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) / length(x)) < na.perc.cutoff]
  cat(paste0("Remaining cols: ", ncol(df)),
      paste0("\nRemaining miss: ", paste0(round(sum(is.na(df)) / prod(dim(df)) * 100, 2), "%\n")))
  print(df)
  if (vis_miss==TRUE) {return(vis_miss(df[1:nrow(df),c(1:ncol(df))], warn_large_data=F))}
}

cut_cols(my.data, 0.5, vis_miss = T)
```

Here's another option if it interests you. You can assign both the df and the plot to a list then call the list.

```
cut_cols <- function(df, na.perc.cutoff, vis_miss=FALSE) {
  df <- df[lapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) / length(x)) < na.perc.cutoff]
  cat(paste0("Remaining cols: ", ncol(df)),
      paste0("\nRemaining miss: ", paste0(round(sum(is.na(df)) / prod(dim(df)) * 100, 2), "%\n")))

  # empty list
  list_ <- c()
  # assign df to first index of list
  list_[[1]] <- df

  if (vis_miss==TRUE){
    plot <- vis_miss(df[1:nrow(df),c(1:ncol(df))], warn_large_data=F)
    # assign plot to second index in list
    list_[[2]] <- plot
  }
  return(list_)
}

output <- cut_cols(my.data, 0.5, vis_miss = T)
```

Calling `output` will print both the df and plot. `output[[1]]` will print just the df. `output[[2]]` will print just the plot.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! What would be the advantge of storing the plot and df in a list?

Comment: Oh I just noticed that `cut_cols() -> out` doesn't work anymore, using the new function (without the list), probably because the function justs "prints" without returning it as an object for further analyses...

Comment: @Fabian the benefit is being able to store both in an object for later use or printing. What is your second comment about? Are you saying the function that puts the output in a list does not print anymore?

Comment: I would like to use it in a pipe command, which currently looks like this (using the list approach): `cut_cols(my.data, 0.5) %>% .[[1]] %>% ... -> new.data`. That works.

Comment: The issue with the other approach (without storing it in a list) was that the function no longer outputs a df for further analysis or more precisely, a df that I could feed into a pipe command.

Comment: I was wondering if this is because it just "prints" the results to the console like a plain "message" without actually returning the df as an object that I could then feed into a `%>%`.